# SQL joining three tables and selecting information

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables

- Doctor - Staff_ID, Name, Position.
- Consists_Of - Staff_Id, Team_Code.
- Team - Team_Code, Telephone_No, Staff_ID

The team table consists of the team leader for each team who is also a doctor,

I need to return a table that has team_code, staff_Id, name, position

I have got

```
SELECT DISTINCT Team.team_code, Doctor.staff_ID, name, position
FROM Doctor, Team LEFT OUTER JOIN consists_of
ON Team.Team_code = consists_of.Team_code
```

But this is giving every each member of stay the team code, t1 and then t2 and then t3 and so on.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need to do a join between doctor and team using staff_id. Are you trying to return all team leaders?

Comment: I don't get what the Consists_Of table is for.

Comment: The consists of is a list of staff ID and the team code they are linked too. The table team contains the team code, telephone no and the team leaders staff_id

Comment: why are you mixing implicit and explicit joins? and why creating cartesian product of `doctor` and `team`? do you want to return the team leader or every member of a team?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is use JOIN. The repetition occurred because you didn't specify on what field should Doctor and Team be joined

```
SELECT Team.team_code, Doctor.staff_ID, name, position
FROM Doctor
LEFT OUTER JOIN consists_of
   ON Doctor.Staff_Id=consists_of.Staff_Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Team 
   ON Team.Team_code = consists_of.Team_code
```

But why do you have Staff_Id in Team table?

Comment: `Team.Staff_ID` is probably a reference to the team's leader.